# Prove that the entire function is constant over certain conditions.

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

> Let $f$ a entire function such that there exists $3$ real numbers not
>   all zero $a$, $b$ and $c$ which $a \Re(f(z))+ b\Im(f(z)) \leq c$, $z
> \in \mathbb{C}$. Show that $f$ is constant.

I think we could consider the entire function $e^{\alpha f(z)}$ with $\alpha=a+bi$. I know that $|e^{\alpha f(z)}|= |e^{\Re({\alpha f(z)})+i \Im({\alpha f(z)})}|=e^{\Re({\alpha f(z)})}$, but I don't know how to finish it.

Is anyone could help at this point? Maybe we have to use Liouville theorem.

Comment: Every function satisfies the inequality with $(a,b,c)= (0,0,1)$. Presumably you mean $(a,b) \neq (0,0)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without loss of generality, we can assume that $|a+ib| =1$. Let
$a+ib= e^{i \theta}$. Then the inequality
becomes
$\Re(e^{- i \theta} f(z)) \le c$ for all $z$.

Let $g(z) = {1 \over 1+c-e^{- i \theta}f(z)}$, then $|g(z)| \le 1$ for all $z$ and hence
$g$ is constant, hence $f$ is constant.

Comment: Divide the inequality across by$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$. Let $a'={a \over \sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$, etc.

Comment: No problem! ${}{}$

Comment: Note that $|1+c + e^{-i \theta} f(z)| \ge 1$ for all $z$.

Comment: I tried to simply doing this : $|e^{\alpha f(z)}|=e^{\Re(e^{- i \theta} f(z))} \leq e^c$ $\implies$ $\Re (e^{- i \theta} f(z)) = k$ where $k$ is a constant. Is it possible to use this simple fact to prove that $f$ is constant?

Comment: Yes, you could use $| e^{e^{-i\theta} f(z)}|  = e^{\operatorname{re} e^{-i\theta} f(z) }  \le e^c$ and continuity (the map $z \mapsto e^{e^{-i\theta} f(z)}$ is not injective).

Comment: Note that $|e^{x+iy}| = |e^{x+niy}|$ for all $n$, so knowing that $|e^{g(z)}|$ is bounded doesn't imply that $g(z)$ is bounded unless you add other conditions (in this case continuity).

Comment: The answer above avoids these issues since the map $w \mapsto {1 \over 1+c - e^{-i \theta} w}$ has a continuous inverse for $w$ in the range of $f$.

Comment: Even if you told me $|1+c + e^{-i \theta} f(z)| \ge 1$, I really don't know how you construct $g$... i.e. How you passed of an inequality with a real part to the $g$ function.

Comment: Even with continuity it is false. 

Define $g(z) = i|z|$. This function is continuous and not bounded. However $e^{g(z)}$ is bounded.

Comment: I don't understand your question. The function $g$ is defined as above, $c,\theta$ are constants, the only question is if $g$ is well defined. Since $\operatorname{re} (1+c + e^{i \theta} f(z)) \ge 1$, we see that (i) $g$ is well defined and (ii) $|g(z)| \le 1$. I am not passing any inequality. If can elaborate your question more I will try to answer, but I'm really not sure what is unclear.

Comment: This mimics the proof that a non constant polynomial $p$ must have a zero. If it doesn't, then the function $z \mapsto {1 \over p(z)}$ is entire and bounded which means it is constant.